# Managed Disk - PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to create a new Managed disk VM with PowerShell. By default it creates premium disk and also generate unique string at the end of disk name. I want to create disk as standard disk and also want to set the name for disk.

I found the command Set-AzureRmosdisk but ita not working with New-AzureRmVMConfig command.

Can someone please help me how to do achieve this ?

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized#create-the-new-vm). Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what's the structure of your script is but the key link to get a standard disk is the **Set-AzureRMVMOSDisk** and the parameter you need to set is **StorageAccountType**

```
Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name $osDiskName -CreateOption FromImage -Windows -StorageAccountType Standard_LRS
```

For Standard you need to specify **StorageAccountType** to be either **StandardSSD_LRS** or **Standard_LRS**

Comment: I have tried this command already but its not accepting "-vm" switch and its not working "-vm" switch as well... I have opened a case with MS to see what they suggest.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do what you want to do, all depends on the structure of your script. If you need help with a particular structure/script you need to share it so we know what you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Found the proper way from below article:

https://savilltech.com/2018/03/17/deploying-an-azure-iaas-vm-using-powershell/

Comment: The line i provided you is the proper way and is in the script in link you shared.